# Crystal report shows blank data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have crystal report that was working before database upgrade. It is only one report that doesnt work. So I would not think of a driver issue.
I am able to test this report using CRs client tools, design and then preview. The preview does not bring any data. A single parameter is used and I am sure there is data because the data is retrieved if I create a new crystal report and also verified the SQL. (So there is no question about the no data or any missing links -- its a simple view).
This cannot be a driver issue as well, as all other old reports still work.
Have also tried deleting all the field's from the report, then add a single/simple new table and preview, still no data is showing.

Are there any logs inside crystal to investigate ?  have tried ODBC.logs doesnt help as doesn't say what happens inside crystal reports after retrieving the data from database.

Thanks.
Zain

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem multiple times where my report comes up with empty fields.  This may not be your cause, but what fixes it for me is to make sure that the dataset/table matches is referred to by the same name everyplace.  In the xxxxxxDataset.xsd file, that table that's pictured should be the same name that's used in the function GetData() As System.Data.DataSet in your .NET object that uses the stored procedure to get the data.  (You may call your function something other than GetData().)  So try changing the ds.Tables(0).Tablename = "xxxxxxxTable" to match what the table in the xsd file is called.